# UILabel Not Updating Consistently

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a very simple update method, where I've included the debugging lines.

```
@IBOutlet weak var meterLabel: UILabel!

func updateMeter(string: String)
{
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        meterLabel.text = string
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            meterLabel.text = string
        }
    }
    print(string)
}
```

Obviously `string` is never nil. The function `updateMeter` is called about 3 times a second, however currently in the simulator I do not see the UILabel change (it does change during calls to this same `updateMeter` elsewhere). Is there any reason why changing a UILabel's text would not have a visible result on the main thread?

Called here:

```
public func startRecording()
{
    let recordingPeriod = TimeInterval(Float(Constants.windowSize)/Float(Constants.sampleFrequency))
    var index = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { timer in
        let audioRecorder = self.AudioRecorders[index]!
        audioRecorder.deleteRecording()
        audioRecorder.record()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + recordingPeriod)
        {
            if let pitch = self.finishSampling(audioRecorder: audioRecorder, index: self.AudioRecorders.index(of: audioRecorder))
            {
                self.meterViewController?.updateMeter(string: String(pitch))
            }
        }
        index = index + 1
        if index == 4 { index = 0 }
        if !(self.keepRecording ?? false) { timer.invalidate() }
    }
}
```

Other methods called:

```
private func finishSampling(audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?, index: Int?) -> Float?
{
    audioRecorder?.stop()
    if let index = index, var (data, _, _) = loadAudioSignal(audioURL: getDirectory(for: index))
    {
        let pitch = getPitch(&data, Int32(data.count), Int32(Constants.windowSize), Int32(Constants.sampleFrequency))
        return Float(pitch)
    }
    return nil
}

private func loadAudioSignal(audioURL: URL) -> (signal: [Float], rate: Double, frameCount: Int)?
{
    guard
        let file = try? AVAudioFile(forReading: audioURL),
        let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false),
        let buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))
        else
    {
        return nil
    }
    try? file.read(into: buf)
    let floatArray = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf.floatChannelData?[0], count:Int(buf.frameLength)))
    return (signal: floatArray, rate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, frameCount: Int(file.length))
}
```

Where `getPitch` does some simple processing and runs relatively quick.

Comment: *"would not have a visible result on the main thread?"* - Something else is blocking the main thread?

Comment: The code gets executed, and actually always goes through the first branch. That is, it is always called on the main thread. I can place breakpoints and see the changed value of meterLabel, but it does not show in the app for some reason. It definitely has a correct reference to the UILabel.

Comment: How are you calling `updateMeter` 3 times per second? Show that code. It sounds like you are not giving the main thread an opportunity to update the UI

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "not giving the main thread an opportunity to update the UI" means. Indeed, once I stop updating the UILabel, it updates according to the last call of `updateMeter(string: String)`. I don't understand why it does not update during the continuous calls.

Note that it does not update even if it is only called, say, once every two seconds.

Comment: Use a `Timer`, don't sleep a thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `usleep` you are blocking the main thread.  The main thread is the thread that updates the UI.  Since it is blocked, it cannot do that.

You should use an alternate approach, such as a `Timer` to periodically update the label.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense to me, but I've tried with a Timer - as edited above. The problem still persists unfortunately.

Comment: Why are you using `asyncAfter` with the timer? What does `finishSampling` do?  It sounds like you are still blocking the thread somewhere.

Comment: There are two time-based operations I want. I want to call `AVAudioRecorder.record()` once every 0.25 seconds (on different recorders), I do this with the `Timer`. I also want to call `AVAudioRecorder.stop()` 0.5 seconds after each record, I do this with `asyncAfter`. For other reasons `AVAudioRecoder.record(forDuration: )` does not suit my purposes.


`finishSampling` processes the audio file slightly. It runs rather quickly; I've called it 15+ times a second before.

Comment: It sounds like you should be executing your timer and dispatching the sampling work on another queue and just dispatching the UI update onto the main queue

Comment: This works, thank you. I don't quite understand it though; by nature of a queue, shouldn't the UI get updated (perhaps delayed slightly) regardless?

Comment: iOS multi tasking is not preemptive. If you block the main thread then the UI update runloop never gets a chance to execute.

Comment: It would work the way you expected if we had a synchronous "flush UI updates to the screen" method but, as far as I know, there's no such beast.